# How to concatenate more than 2 fields with SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to use CONCAT with SQL to concatenate 3 fields, and get the following error:

Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'

The query is as follows

```
SELECT CONCAT(guests.lastname,', ',guests.firstname', ',guests.passport) AS display 
  FROM guests 
 WHERE guests.uuid = '1'
```

How do you concatenate more than 2 fields in SQL?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You must put commas between all the arguments.

Change:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(guests.lastname,', ',guests.firstname', ',guests.passport)
```

to:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(guests.lastname,', ',guests.firstname,', ',guests.passport) 
                                                    ^
```

Comment: I've found that Doctrine only accepts two arguments for its CONCAT function.  http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-670  Not a simple syntax error in my case.  Work around being expressing it like: `CONCAT(a, CONCAT(b, CONCAT(c, d)))`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONCAT(guests.lastname,concat(', ',concat(guests.firstname,concat(', ',guests.passport))));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONCAT(guests.lastname,', ',guests.firstname', ',guests.passport) AS display 
FROM guests 
WHERE guests.uuid = '1'
```

Kindly try the below one,

```
SELECT guests.lastname||','||guests.firstname||','|| guests.passport AS display 
  FROM guests 
 WHERE guests.uuid = '1'
```