# SELECT * with Concatenation of student name

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this query

```
GetRecords = conn.RetriveQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE StudentID = " & studetId)
```

which will output a table with the following columns:

```
Student ID | Lastname | Firstname | Middlename | Gender | DOB | address | Contact | Email
```

Is there a way to create a short query which concatenates `lastname`,`firtsname`,`middlename` as a fullname, so that the output would be

```
Student ID | Fullname | Gender | DOB | Address | Contact | Email
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate more than 2 fields with SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182555/how-to-concatenate-more-than-2-fields-with-sql)

Comment: In general, you should not use `SELECT *` in real code. The database is free to return the columns in any order if you do that. It will *almost* always return them as you expect - not *always*. You should explicitly state the columns which you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CONCAT function in Mysql.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`Firstname`, ' ', `Lastname`) FROM `table`
```

At least something to the effect above. That should get you the desired result. Although,  I would suggest to do the concat in your VB code instead of mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Select FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' Surname as [Full Name] 
 from tbl_Students 
 WHERE StudentID = ?
```