# How to concatenate more than 2 SQL columns?

Tags: php, sql

As described in the title, I would like to concatenate more than 2 columns in my SQL query like this:
`$reqArticles = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM articles WHERE CONCAT(title, content, author, location) LIKE "%'.$element.'%" ORDER BY id DESC');` 
This returns an empty array unlike when I enter only 2 parameters in "CONCAT".
PS: there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182555/how-to-concatenate-more-than-2-fields-with-sql) but its answer does not correspond to my need.

EDIT :
the data looks like this :

```
`id = 1
fields = contents_fields
title = 'the football'
content =' Football is the most popular sport in the world '
author = 'Patrick'
location = 'French'`
```

And the output I'm waiting for must contain all the ids of the items in the "element" to be found

Re-Edit :

Important things I forgot: the `location` field is often null.
I think that's where the error comes from because I did a small test by removing this field and leaving the other 3 the request works correctly. But to be confirmed.

so the data looks more like this:

```
`id = 1
fields = contents_fields
title = 'the football'
content =' Football is the most popular sport in the world '
author = 'Patrick'
location = 'French' or NULL`
```

Comment: Please could you post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Why does the question linked to not correspond to your needs?

Comment: `CONCAT` can take any number of columns. What does `$element` contain and what does the database have that should match? Separate note possibly unrelated `$element` should not be in the `prepare` function, that should be a placeholder and be being bound.

Comment: @ 
DhruvJoshi I have made the necessary changes, @ 
Nigel Ren Because the answers suggest to put a comma between each parameter and that's what I already do and @ 
utilisateur3783243 can you be more precise please? I don't really understand

Comment: `LIKE concat("%", ?, "%") ORDER BY id DESC` then bind in `$element`. Not clear if using PDO or mysqli here so cant advise on which bind function is correct. `var_dump($element)` gives what?

Comment: var_dump gives an empty array and I use PDO. And also I made a last modification that must be important

Comment: If `var_dump` is empty then that is your issue.  You are not setting `$element` correctly. How is that being assigned? You can pass that to an array in the `execute` function since you are using PDO. That will allow it to bind correctly. Please use `@` so notifications are used.

Comment: excuse me var_dump gives this: 'object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(111) "SELECT id FROM events WHERE CONCAT(title, author, location, content) LIKE "%Football%" ORDER BY id DESC" }'. I had done 'var_dump(element->fetchAll)'

Comment: `$element` should not be a PDO object. It should be a string. You ran what was provided?? You also need to use `@`s or notifications will not be sent.

Comment: @
utilisateur3783243 var_dump($element) == string(8) "Football";

Answer (score -1):

try printing the concat part of the query to confirm that the output is correct.
As you indicated in the post, you may have to write CONCAT(title,CONCAT(content,CONCAT(author, location)))

Comment: Why would multiple `concat`s be needed?

Comment: it doesn't work with my location field. see the re-edit for more explanations